# Where I can get a copy of patent no. ZL94105912.X

Tags: laser

Could you please help me to get a copy for a copy of patent no. ZL94105912.X
regards
Essam hamed

Answer (score 2):

That number is for a patent in China. It is a format used in China for granted patents. In most western databases a differently formatted number starting with CN is used.  I found the patent [here](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/89/0c/a4/2fcca701366bf9/CN1045724C.pdf) [image: front page of patent] Under its "CN" number it is CN1045724C.